# How to navigate back to current page from Frame in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

How to navigate back to main page from an `iframe`?

Example:

```
driver.SwitchTo.Frame(1);

driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Is not working.
Can anyone suggest any other way to retain control?

Comment: Do you see any kind of error when you attempt to return via `switchTo().defaultContent()`?

Comment: no error..Its showing frame page only

Comment: Can you interact with the page normally BEFORE you `switchTo().Frame(1)`?

Comment: `defaultContent()` works. You are probably doing something slightly different from what it is designed to do. Could you show us your code, or even a working reproducible testcase which shows the problem? Have you tried different browsers?

Answer (score 7):

This is the way recommended at seleniumeasy [Working with frames](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-work-with-iframes-in-selenium-webdriver)

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 5):

You could always directly switch back to the window using:

```cs
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

try
`driver.SwitchTo.Frame(0);`

another idea might be to check the check the page source, and switch to the main frame by using its actual frame name.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me (Ruby)

```
driver.switch_to.default_content
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```